# Simple Compounding vs Continuous Compounding in return series

Tags: programming, returns, log-returns, compounding

I'm creating a log price series in MATLAB. This is fairly easy to do using standard functions. Given a price series `prices`:

`r = diff(log(prices))` will give you the standard log return series calculated by

$r = \ln(P_t) - \ln(P_{t-1})$

However, I'd like to use the [tick2ret](https://www.mathworks.com/help/finance/tick2ret.html) function in the Financial Toolbox to keep my tooling consistent. Here's where the confusion starts:

I've always referred to `r` above as the "continually compounded return series". Perhaps this is incorrect. `tick2ret` calculates, by default, the "simple compounding return series". Curious, I made another return series:

`r2 = tick2ret(prices)`

and as it turns out `r` and `r2` are virtually the same aside from rounding. I expected the "simple compounded returns" to be calculated using

$r = \frac{P_t - P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}}$

However, according to my calculation they are using the log return calculation.

Am I misunderstanding simple and compound returns? Can the log return series be calculated using simple compounding? I think I am getting lost in terminology.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\Delta P = P_t - P_{t-1}$ and expand the continuously compounded return in a Taylor series
$$ r = \log\left(\frac{P_t}{P_{t-1}}\right) = \log\left(\frac{P_{t-1}+\Delta P}{P_{t-1}}\right) = \log\left(1+\frac{\Delta P}{P_{t-1}}\right) \approx \frac{\Delta P}{P_{t-1}} - \mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{\Delta P}{P_{t-1}}\right)^2\right) = \frac{P_t - P_{t-1}}{P_{t-1}} - \mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{\Delta P}{P_{t-1}}\right)^2\right)
$$
If $\Delta P/P_{t-1}$ is small, which is typically the case for daily or shorter time frames, the higher order terms can be neglected and the continuously compounded return is approximately equal to the simple return.

Comment: so then what is happening is that since my returns are so small they're basically the same? Good to know. I'll need to keep this in mind if I use `tick2ret` on anything larger than daily.